# How to keep extension pop up to remain open when new tab is clicked

Tags: google-chrome-extension

my extension close when link in the extension is clicked
How to keep extension pop up to remain open when new tab is clicked

Answer (score 0):

In general, that's not possible as stated in [Chrome Extensions FAQ](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/faq#faq-persist-popups):

> **Can extensions keep popups open after the user clicks away from them?**
>
> No, popups automatically close when the user focuses on some portion of the browser outside of the popup. There is no way to keep the popup open after the user has clicked away.

However, if you inspect the popup, it will stay open as long as you don't close the Developer Tools window.

For end users, the only thing you could do is use a tab instead of a popup if that works better for your use case, or just inject your code into a specific tab to show your interface on top of/next to a page, as some extensions like [Siteimprove](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/siteimprove-accessibility/efcfolpjihicnikpmhnmphjhhpiclljc) do.

Comment: can user see previous content when he open popup again

Comment: @SachinPrajapati You should use [`chrome.storage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage), [`Window.localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) or [`Window.sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) to persist user's data between visits.